# Drag and Drop files from Package explorer to custom view in eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, drag-and-drop, eclipse-rcp, file-transfer

I am creating plugin which has view, my requirement is like I need to drag and drop files from package explorer to created plugin view. and I am little bit new to plugin development can someone guide me how to process on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-DND/DND-in-SWT.html and https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Workbench-DND/drag_drop.html cover it pretty well, with the Eclipse SDK sources themselves acting as further examples.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I have referred above links. Here I am not able to  define DragSource is Package explorer and DropTarget is TableViewer. can u provide any ideas

Comment: Package Explorer already defines a `DragSource` for itself. What you need to concern yourself with is which transfer types it supports and adding drop support to your viewer.

Comment: yes you are right my viewer should support FileTransfer. as I need to drag java file onto the viewer.

Comment: any idea how to add Drop support to TableViewer

Comment: I think everything you need is in those articles, and just needs a little experimentation on your part.